# Git: Cannot seem to save merge message (Debugger entered--Lisp error)

Tags: git, macos, terminal, git-merge

So, I am trying my hand at using git for the first time.

I have created my repo and pushed an initial bit of code, then I created a readme file on github which meant that origin was ahead.

When I tried to git push I got the message that I should first git pull. Which I did.

I then got this message:

[image]

so I pressed `esc` then `:wq` and then enter.

Then, I got this:

[image]

What the hell do I do?

Comment: Looks like emacs it set as your editor (`$EDITOR` variable?) and you are expecting `vi`?  Sounds like you haven't [configured git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration) for your use at all...

Comment: @trojanfoe Is correct, you're using Emacs as your editor, not VI. VI is using `:wq` to write-quite. Try hitting `Ctrl-X` and then `Ctrl-C`.

Comment: @trojanfoe - Hey, so I am 100% new to git. I set up up, set my ssh keys and got my push etc working. This was completely new to me. I didnt even know there were several editors, I jusy googled "save merge message" etc.. and followed instructions. Downloading Vi now using brew and will set it as editor.

Comment: No, use VSCode! ;-)  Besides `vi` is already installed on macOS out-of-the-box.